# JQuery remove () not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a dynamic table using JQuery, Where a button is clicked to add and remove rows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 2;
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("table").append("<tr id='r" + i + "' ><td>" + i+++"<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
      });

      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        if (i > 2) {
          $("#r" + i).remove();
          i--;
        } else {
          alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</1>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>

</body>

</html>
```

The first click on the delete button does not seem to work properly. 
Only the counter "i" get decreased by one but no row is being deleted.
As a result, when adding an item the "#" will always be the same as the item before it. I couldn't figure out what is the mistake I'm doing to get such a result.

Comment: Try to use ``.on('click',function () { // something }``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 1;
        $("#btn1").click(function() {
        i++;
        $("table").append("<tr id='r" + i + "' ><td>" + i +"<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
      });


      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        if (i > 2) {
          $("#r" + i).remove();
          i--;
        } else {
          alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</1>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some modifications to your code. Instead of keeping a variable `i` to keep track of latest row id, you should base your calculations on the number of rows currently present in the table. This is more reliable and flexible than tracking it using the variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var i = $("#mytable tr").length + 1;
        $("table").append("<tr id='r" + i + "' ><td>" + i + "<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
      });

      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        var i = $("#mytable tr").length;
        if (i > 1) {
          $("#r" + i).remove();
        } else {
          alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table id="mytable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</1>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm just new  to the world of HTML and JQuery. I'll consider doing that for the next times.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The delete button works if you click it first. The issue you have is tracking the state of the `i` variable correctly, which is why this pattern is more of a pain than it's worth.

From the look of your code, all you need to do is ensure that there is at least 1 row in the table. If so, you can just check the number of `tr` elements currently in the table on click of the delete button, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    var $tr = $('table tr');
    $tr.last().after("<tr><td>" + ($tr.length + 1) + "<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var $tr = $('table tr');
    if ($tr.length > 1) {
      $tr.last().remove();
    } else {
      alert("Row cannot be deleted!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
<button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>
```

Comment: This works well, except whille deleting, it starts throwing a warning even when one deletable row is left. Assuming that all rows except the header can be deleted.

Comment: Your table has no header? Do you mean that there should always be at least one row in the table, not two? If so I updated the answer for you

Comment: Sorry, I am not the OP. But you can try running your code. Add first row( it will have number 2 ). Now, try to delete it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Also I updated the code to enforce a single row only

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line `$("#r" + i).remove();`

You need to change it to `(i-1)`

```
 $("#btn2").click(function() {
      console.log(i)
        if (i > 2) {
          $("#r" + (i-1)).remove(); // changed here
          i--;
        } else {
          alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
        }
      });
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vpzww50j/)

Comment: And this if (i > 2)  has to be if (i >= 2) to match from first delete

Comment: I tried to replace mine by what you suggested but, it did not seem to work

Comment: i have attached a jsfiddle check that

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the following code might be a cleaner version over the provided structure. 
If your button is part of the same row, you can do it by calling this method and passing that row to the method

**JS function to delete the row**

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('Yourtable').deleteRow(i);
}
```

**Calling Function**

This is the place where you dynamically create your delete button nd the table itself

```
deletebtn.onclick = function() {
        deleteRow(this);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

just decrement i sooner:

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      i--;
      $("#r" + i).remove();
    } else {
      alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

insitaily while trying to delete you have incremented alreay the i+++

```
 <td>" + i+++"<td>
```

so it increases the i values while trying to delete obviously the ID wont be there thats why this problem you can **try like this**

```
 $("#r" + (i-1)).remove();
```

for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/IxnGt0PVMoXiS5lj6g0Q?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Example that may help

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var next = $('table tr').length + 1;
        $("table").append("<tr id='r" + next + "' ><td>"+ next +"<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
      });

      $("#btn2").click(function() {
          $("table tr:last()").remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</1>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 2;
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("table").append("<tr id='r" + i + "' ><td>" + i+++"<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");
      });

      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        if (i > 2) {
          $("#r" + (i-1)).remove();
          i--;
        } else {
          alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</1>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
  <button id="btn2">Delete Item</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            i++;
            $("table").append("<tr id='r" + i + "' ><td>" + i + "<td><input type='text' /></td></tr>");

        });

        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            if (i > 1) {

                $("#r" + i).remove();
                i--;
            } else {
                alert("Row Cannot Be Deleted !");
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                1</1>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <button id="btn1">
        Add Item</button>
    <button id="btn2">
        Delete Item</button>
</body>
</html>
```